# Смена региона в Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud

Когда разворачивали приложение, я выбрал неправильный регион(Азия), а мне нужно было выбрать европу. Я могу поменять регион?

Comment: А какие конкретно ресурсы в Google Cloud? App Engine? Compute с виртуальными машинами? Что-то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Compute Engine

В этом ресурсе можно менять регионы отдельных инстансов виртуальных машин. Например, используя консольную утилиту Google Cloud:

```bsh
gcloud compute instances move example-instance \
  --zone us-central1-a --destination-zone us-east1-b
```

Более подробно смотрите [в документации](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones).

## App Engine, FireStore, BigQuery

У этих ресурсов невозможно поменять регион после создания проекта, к сожалению, остаётся только пересоздавать проекты и переносить данные вручную.

По этому вопросу в ишью-трекере Гугла уже который год висит фича-реквест, его можно апнуть и принять участие в обсуждении: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36878762